# htaccess redirect in subdomain

Tags: css, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am created a sub domain www.support.rdmac.org.uk which works fine except that it has no styling. Having looked at several forums it seems like the browser needs to be directed towards the domain name for .css files.

At present it is:

> "link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
>   href="http://www.support.rdmac.org.uk/wp-content/themes/twentyten/style.css"
>   /".

I think it should be:

> "link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
>   href="http://www.rdmac.org.uk/wp-content/themes/twentyten/style.css"
>   /"

I have created an .htaccess file in my subdomain folder and used the following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^themes/twentyten/style.css$ http://www.rdmac.org.uk/wp-content/themes/twentyten/style.css[L]
```

This is not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: Where you have placed the .htaccess?

Comment: I have put the .htaccess file in the public_html/support folder where I loaded the Wordpress files.

Comment: I have discovered that I also have a .htaccess in the main domain in public-html. It looks like 

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Should I have 2 .htaccess files?

Answer (score 1):

If the htaccess is at the top level of your subdomain, perhaps you could add 'wp-content/' to the start of the rule.  Formally the end should be " [R,L]", but I understand the R for rewrite is assumed when apache sees an external URL in the rewrite target.

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/themes/twentyten/style.css$ http://www.rdmac.org.uk/wp-content/themes/twentyten/style.css [L]
```

Update:

However I see that your support subdomain appears to be using nginx.   If this is the case then I think you need to look at how you configure nginx redirects instead of apache style htaccess directives on this server.

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding wp-content into the address but it still fails. I will look into the how to configure nginx redirects. Im very much a learner in this area.